# Selenium webdriver - prefs ignored when using specific Chrome profile

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I read a lot of answers about setting a download directory for Chrome, but couldn't find anything when you want to save a file to a specific directory, different from the default one, and you are using a specific profile.

The below code works fine, and when I download a file, it gets saved to the intended `downloadFolderPath`:

```
downloadFolderPath = 'P:\\reports\\attachments'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": downloadFolderPath,
               "directory_upgrade": True,
               "safebrowsing.enabled": True }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
options.headless = False 

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)
# browse to the page, click download, etc.
```

But when I try to do the same, this time using a specific Chrome profile, by adding `user-data-dir` and `profile-directory` arguments:

```
downloadFolderPath = 'P:\\reports\\attachments'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\my.name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 5')
preferences = {
               "download.default_directory": downloadFolderPath,
               "directory_upgrade": True,
               "safebrowsing.enabled": True
               }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
options.headless = False  

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)
# browse the page and download the file
```

Chrome indeed gets opened with the chosen profile, but the file that I download gets saved under the user profile default directory, `C:\Users\my.name\Downloads` instead of the one that I defined (`P:\reports\attachments`). It seems therefore that the preferences passed with `options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)` are ignored when a profile different from the default one is used.

Or is there any different argument that needs to be used when working with specific profiles?

For info, I am on Windows 10, Python 3.9, using Chrome 95.0.4638.54 and chromedriver.exe is 95.0.4638.17

Thanks